# What is the appropriate Javafx container to store rows of labels

Tags: user-interface, javafx, user-controls

I am looking for a container to hold multiple labels. Looking to copy behavior of Gmail when one adds recipients to Compose message dialogue.

It should add labels to a row while space permits. Once label is greater than the remaining space it should add label to next line.

Currently I use List of `HBox`es, but I have to manually compute remaining space. Is there a container that would just go to next line when current line doesn't have enough space.

Labels have different width, so GridLayout wouldn't work very well.

---

Just to be clear. Container is wider than each label, so this question is NOT about "how to make a multiline label?" - "use \n"

Comment: Also you may want to use `Text` nodes instead of `Label`s to avoid getting a ellipsis...

Comment: You can use Toolbar and change orientation to vertical.